# JavaScript Array.splice() method first argument(starting index)

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I was reading about **.splice()** method in MDN. When I got to the first parameter(starting index) I understood all cases but the last one.
What does *"and will be set to 0 if absolute value is greater than the length of the array"* exactly means?

> **Parameters**
>
> **start**
>   Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If
>   greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be
>   set to the length of the array. If negative, will begin that many
>   elements from the end of the array (with origin -1) **and will be set to
>   0 if absolute value is greater than the length of the array.**

[Link to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: What part don't you understand? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value

Comment: If you have a 5-entry array and you pass `-15` as the first argument, it treats it as if you passed `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) is greater than the array length it will do the same thing as if you passed `0`.

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
arr.splice(-8, 1); 
// Absolute value is 8, array length is 7
// Because 8 > 7, the first parameter is set to 0
// So this is the same as arr.splice(0, 1);

console.log(arr);
```